# Sencha CMD Ant integration for custom web application

Tags: sencha-cmd

We are trying to integrate the Sencha CMD to our custom application ant script( build.xml) inorder to do minification of js files. Could you please let us know the steps needs to be followed for minifcation of js files . It could be useful if you could provide sample file to achieve this. We tried the following steps as per the manual to just include the sencha.jar which resulted in error "init-sencha-cmd: 
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml."

I have added the target "init-sencha-cmd" as dependency to target "build" and a property build.dir (basedir="." configured in the start of xml)

```
<target name="build" depends="init, dependencies, pre-compile, compile, post-compile,init-sencha-cmd" description="Builds the project." /> 
<property name="build.dir" location="${basedir}"/> 

<target name="init-antcontrib"> 
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"> 
<classpath> 
<pathelement location="${Bundles.WebCharts.lib}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/> 
</classpath> 
</taskdef> 
</target> 

<target name="init-sencha-cmd" depends="init-antcontrib"> 
<taskdef resource="com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml" classpath="/Users/hatamm/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.0.3.324/sencha.jar"/> 
</target>
```